# Python TypeError on regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, typeerror

So, I have this code:

```
url = 'http://google.com'
linkregex = re.compile('<a\s*href=[\'|"](.*?)[\'"].*?>')
m = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
msg = m.read()
links = linkregex.findall(msg)
```

But then python returns this error:

```
links = linkregex.findall(msg)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Which version of Python are you running?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> `TypeError: can't use a string pattern`
> `on a bytes-like object`
>
> what did i do wrong??

You used a string pattern on a bytes object. Use a bytes pattern instead:

```
linkregex = re.compile(b'<a\s*href=[\'|"](.*?)[\'"].*?>')
                       ^
            Add the b there, it makes it into a bytes object
```

(ps:

```
 >>> from disclaimer include dont_use_regexp_on_html
 "Use BeautifulSoup or lxml instead."
```

)

Comment: Will it break with python2?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Python 2.6 then there isn't any "request" in "urllib". So the third line becomes:

```
m = urllib.urlopen(url)
```

And in version 3 you should use this:

```
links = linkregex.findall(str(msg))
```

Because 'msg' is a bytes object and not a string as findall() expects. Or you could decode using the correct encoding. For instance, if "latin1" is the encoding then:

```
links = linkregex.findall(msg.decode("latin1"))
```

Comment: He says in the comments that he's running 3.1.3, so there *is* a `request`.

Comment: Indeed, saw that afterwards. So I added the solution for version 3 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my version of Python doesn't have a urllib with a request attribute but if I use "urllib.urlopen(url)" I don't get back a string, I get an object.  This is the type error.

Comment: Here is the link to docs backing this up: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen

Comment: Those are docs for 2.7.  The OP says in the comments that he's using 3.1.3.

Comment: John, read the docs.  The API is still the same.

Comment: My point is, *your* version doesn't have the request attribute, but the OP's version *does*.  You are correct on the cause of the type error.

Comment: Yeah, the version was mentioned after I put my answer up.  ;)

Comment: I misread the question I guess.  Thanks for the down vote.

Comment: Yes, you get an object. But if you then do a read() on that object you get a string. But however, under Python 3, you get a bytes object. This is a Python 3 issue, and has to do with the separation of binary and text data under Python 3. This answer is incorrect and not useful. Sorry.

Comment: @Jeremy: I didn't downvote you.  I don't know who did, but I was downvoted too.  Why would someone downvote us all like this?

Answer (score 1):

The url you have for Google didn't work for me, so I substituted `http://www.google.com/ig?hl=en` for it which works for me.

Try this:

```
import re
import urllib.request

url="http://www.google.com/ig?hl=en"
linkregex = re.compile('<a\s*href=[\'|"](.*?)[\'"].*?>')
m = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
msg = m.read():
links = linkregex.findall(str(msg))
print(links)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This only works if your system Python default encoding is the same as the web pages encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression pattern and string have to be of the same type. If you're matching a regular string, you need a string pattern. If you're matching a byte string, you need a bytes pattern.

In this case *m.read()* returns a byte string, so you need a bytes pattern. In Python 3, regular strings are unicode strings, and you need the *b* modifier to specify a byte string literal:

```
linkregex = re.compile(b'<a\s*href=[\'|"](.*?)[\'"].*?>')
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me in python3. Hope this helps

```
import urllib.request
import re
urls = ["https://google.com","https://nytimes.com","http://CNN.com"]
i = 0
regex = '<title>(.+?)</title>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)

while i < len(urls) :
    htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    titles = re.search(pattern, str(htmltext))
    print(titles)
    i+=1
```

And also this in which i added **b** before regex to convert it into byte array.

```
import urllib.request
import re
urls = ["https://google.com","https://nytimes.com","http://CNN.com"]
i = 0
regex = b'<title>(.+?)</title>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)

while i < len(urls) :
    htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    titles = re.search(pattern, htmltext)
    print(titles)
    i+=1
```