# What should I do this error in Python

Tags: python, findall

```
# -*- coding: cp949 -*-

import urllib.request
import re
url="http://google.co.kr"
value=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
par='<title>(.+?)</title>'
result=re.findall(par,value)
print(result)
```

In this code I met Error in line 8

```
"TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object" And
"File"C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 210, in findall"
```

Help me please.

Comment: could you print `type(value)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python TypeError on regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184483/python-typeerror-on-regex)

Comment: @VigneshKalai  It is <class 'bytes'>

Comment: @Andersson you are right

Comment: @Andersson Thank you. How do I fix it?

Comment: @VigneshKalai Thank you. How do I fix it?

Comment: `par=b'<title>(.+?)</title>'` you have to use byte regex on byte object.It can be done by adding `b`

Comment: @VigneshKalai Thank you!!! This Error got solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`urllib.request.urlopen().read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) returns byte-string. You will need to `decode()` it to get the string, Example -

```
value=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('cp949')
```

Used cp949 since you seem to be using that in your header - `# -*- coding: cp949 -*-` , you can use any encoding you want, you can also leave it blank, so the it gets decoded using the default encoding.