# about the re module in python

Tags: python, regex, decode, encode, bytecode

I'm running a snippest like that:

```
p = re.compile(b'^((?!-)[*A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$')
m = p.match(domain)
```

'domain' are the ip addresses get from google dns. I know there is something wrong with the decoding, so I've tried to encode the regular expressions after it was compiled, but still get the bug notice like this,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\python34\lib\threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "update.py", line 101, in run
  if validate_domain(domain):
File "update.py", line 182, in validate_domain
  m = pattern.match(domain)
TypeError: can't use a bytes pattern on a string-like object
```

Could you give me some tips for this situation

!!!Programming language: python 3.4

Comment: get rid of the `b`

Comment: First link on google for the given error message is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5184483/1324033)

Comment: Any reason you're using `b''` instead of `r''`?

Answer (score 1):

Appending a `b` to the start of your pattern makes it a bytes object. But you can't match string objects with a bytes pattern. The error is quite clear:

```
p = re.compile(b'^((?!-)[*A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$')
#              ^
```

You probably intended to use `r''`

Comment: why was this downvoted? I would have said the same thing.