# Python - TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
import re

meshTerm = {}
meshNumber = {}

File = 'file.bin'
with open(File, mode='rb') as file:
    readFile = file.read()

outputFile = open('output.txt', 'w')

for line in readFile:
    term= re.search(r'MH = .+', line)
    print(term)
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myFile.py", line 13, in <module>
    term = re.search(r'MH = .+', line)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\re.py", line 173, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Why is that? How can I solve the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading the *whole* file using binary mode `'rb'` in this line;

```
with open(File, mode='rb') as file:
    readFile = file.read()
```

So that makes your readFile a bytes array, and when you loop through the readFile in the following manner it gives you a single byte. Which python assumes is an integer.

```
>> for line in readFile:
>>     print(line)
>>     print(type(line))
116
<class 'int'>
104
<class 'int'>
105
<class 'int'>
...
```

I think you meant to read the file line by line;

```
with open(File, mode='rb') as file:
    readFile = file.readlines()
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I'm now getting this error: TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: This answers the above error. It seems I should use a byte pattern instead of a string pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184483/python-typeerror-on-regex

Comment: @Simplicity oh sorry, yeah you can do that or read the file in text mode by changing `'rb'` to `'r'` if you have strings in the file.